# Read data from a file using Command Prompt

Tags: c++, command-prompt, file-io

I have a C++ .exe that I want to read data from a file, using command prompt. I was told to type in `prog.exe < case.in` , but this only works if both files are in the `C:\Users\Owner> folder`. Is there a way I can make this work for having both of the files in different locations?

Comment: Use absolute paths to both files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the full path or use a relative path to the input. For example, if the input file is in `D:\somewhere\else`:

`prog.exe < "D:\somewhere\else\input.in"`

Answer (score 0):

You may have
 `prog.exe "/path/to/case.in"`
 or even
`/path/to/prog.exe "/path/to/case.in"`